# error in AlertDialog box of android while showing the other layout in to it

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i am new to android. in my application i have a  button .i put a onClick listener  to it and in onClick function i am looking to take a alert dilago .and looking to inflate a layout on to it.it is xml file from layouts.in that xml i putt a edite text and spinner .after runnig the application i am able to get that layout xml file on to alertdilago .there is no problem with iflating that onto it.

The problem here is as i am trying to enter something onto edittext and try to to press the positive button the application is getting closed.

in onclick i am writing the code as follows

```
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View addView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_alert, null);
            final EditText input= new EditText(this);
        final Spinner inputsp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spalert);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(NewGbrainyActivity.this)
                .setTitle("ENTER YOUR DETAILS")
                .setView(addView)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {

                                }

                                String value = input.getText().toString();

                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                                        "com.pakage.android.newgbrainy.LEVELS");
                                myIntent.putExtra("name", value);

                                int requestCode = 1;
                                startActivityForResult(myIntent,
                                        requestCode);

                                // finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                // Do nothing.
                                dialog.dismiss();


                            }
                        }).show();
```

how should i write the code for taking input and pass it to another activity.please help me

Thank you,
maddy.

Comment: what exception you are getting in logcat

Comment: Please add logcat screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying "In that xml I putt a edite text and spinner." if so then you should get the Editext from the xml layout. Instead to create new. Also get spinner view from xml

```
 final EditText input= new EditText(this);
 final Spinner inputsp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spalert);
```

do this

```
final EditText input= (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.my_editext_id);
final Spinner inputsp = (Spinner) addView.findViewById(R.id.spalert);
```

Comment: thank you very much for explaing me this sir.it worked great for me

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code lines,

```
View addView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_alert, null);
final EditText input= (EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
final Spinner inputsp = (Spinner)addView.findViewById(R.id.spalert);
```